# I dont get the proper jar Files for PowerMock to Mock private Methods?

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

I am trying to mock a private method but I am unable to load the proper jar Files for PowerMockito. I used to get errors like

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javassist.Modifier.isPackage(I)Z
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.allowMockingOfPackagePrivateClasses(MainMockTransformer.java:85)
    at .......
```

Comment: You need to use the right version of the javassist library that comes with your version of PowerMockito. Either you have the wrong version on your classpath, or you have multiple versions on your classpath and the wrong one is first. Either way, remove all the wrong versions and make sure that the right version is on your classpath.

Comment: I have javassist-3.20.0,PowerMockito-1.6.4,Mockito-1.10.8. Are these versions of mine correct or should I use a different version

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I get the following error to...`The type org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`